# Как на андроиде программно построить диаграмму Ганта?

Tags: android, java

Появилась задачка вывести данные в диаграмму. Погуглив, ничего интересного не нашел, вернее только пару статей по столбчатым диаграммам. Но мне надо именно Ганта. Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Поискав еще инфу, нашел 2 компонента, но один коммерческий и большой по объему, другой давно разработчики забросили. В общем, вопрос открыт((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем то великих проблем не вижу. В качестве основы надо брать `ListView` с шириной больше экрана (поскольку Гант имеет тенденцию роста вширь).

В качестве элементов `ListView` надо брать какой-то хитрый `View` скомпонованный из `ImageView` (для рисования столбиков) и `TextView` с текстом.

Comment: Проблема в том, что дроидописанием занимаюсь недавно(( Вот проблема еще в этом самом "хитром" View. Думал, может, есть какие-то готовые библиотеки.